# Store sockets in Nodejs with multi process

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a NodeJS TCP server that stores each socket connection in an array with some misc info I need to be associated with them:

```
var clients = [];

net.createServer(sslOptions, function (_socket) {
    _socket.name = 'someName';
    _sockect.foo = 'bar';
    clients.push(_socket);
}
```

The server iterates the array *clients* quite often for some business logic stuff. Sometimes a condition triggers and I need to disconnect one of those sockets:

```
if(condition) {
  for(let x = 0; x < clients.length; x++) {
    if(clients[x].name == 'someName') {
      clients[x].disconnect();
      clients.splice(x, 1);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

There are 2 things that worry me about this approach. If I decided to replicate my app for load balancing using something like [PM2 clusters](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#cluster-mode) or any other Nodejs Process Manager, how can the different process share the same array *clients*? And what happens if a process is iterating the array while other is removing an index, there could be race conditions that can eventually lead to mistaken disconnections and deletion.

A solution, of course, is to use something like an atomic DB, but I don't know how can I store a socket in something like Mongo or Redis.

Answer (score 2):

> How can the different process share the same array clients?

They don't.

Two node.js processes can't access the same array (they are in separate processes and separate Javascript interpreters) so there is no opportunity for direct data sharing or a corresponding race condition in that regard.

> And what happens if a process is iterating the array while other is removing an index, there could be race conditions that can eventually lead to mistaken disconnections and deletion.

Because Javascript runs all your Javascript in only a single thread, you can't have multiple pieces of Javascript both trying to modify the same array at the same time.  If you are iterating an array and making async calls, there are some safety things you need to do because the array could change while waiting for an async response, but it can't change while your synchronous `for` loop is running for example.

To understand how you can make something like you have work with multiple node.js processes, you can learn a lot from how the socket.io server supports clustering because it has the same basic issue to solve.  They want to be able to emit to all connected sockets (across all clustered servers) or to any specific connection (no matter which server the message originates on and which server the connected client is actually connected to).

For socket.io, they basically use a common intermediary store that all clustered processes can access (a redis data store in their case).  Since redis is designed for multi-user access, a client can use its APIs carefully and avoid race conditions.  The redis store is then used to store meta data about each connected user and an indicator for which server process contains their current connection.

To send a message to a specific user from any of the clustered server processes, you fetch the data for that user from the redis store.  If the user is on the connected to the local server process (the one you're doing the lookup from), then you can just directly get their ID from the metadata and look them up in your own local list of connected clients and send to their socket.

If they are connected to a different server, then you send that server a message asking them to relay a message to a particular socket ID value.  When that server receives the message, it looks up that ID in it's own list of clients that are connected to its process, gets their socket and sends them a message.

As clients connect or disconnect from any of the clustered processes, connections are added or removed from the redis store.  Keep in mind that you don't (and can't) store an actual socket object in the redis store because a socket object is local to a particular process.  You store meta data only in the redis store and a server ID so anyone querying the redis store can determine which users are connected and which server they are currently connected to.  You would typically use a unique username or some other unique ID to represent each user and similarly servers would be represented by some sort of ID (perhaps a host/port number) that allows you to connect to them.

To avoid race conditions in the redis store, you just need to use good multi-user data management practices and the correct redis APIs when modifying data and most problems will be avoided.  Further advice on race conditions would require more specifics about what you're trying to modify.  But, mostly you'll just be adding a connected user upon connection, removing a connected user upon disconnect and those are both atomic operations when done with the right APIs.  If you are fetching a list of users and then operating on them, you will have a potential race conditions if they disconnect between the time you queried them and then when you tried to actually send to them.  For that, you just have to be prepared to handle errors appropriately if they happen to be gone when you try to message them.

Each individual node.js process would maintain its own array of sockets that are connected to its own process.  Since node.js runs JS as single threaded and that array is not shared with any other process or thread, there are no opportunities for race conditions in just accessing or maintaining that array if your code is written properly.

> A solution, of course, is to use something like an atomic DB, but I don't know how can I store a socket in something like Mongo or Redis.

You don't store a socket in those databases.  You store a socket ID value and a server ID value.  The server ID value (which could be a host/port string) can be used to connect to the right server that has a connection for that socket ID.  The socket ID can then be used by the receiving server to look up the actual socket object for its own connection in its own array.

Answer (score 0):

I think u must consider to use [Socket.io Redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) instead.
They store clients in RedisAdapter. You can get list of client IDs by:

```
io.of('/').adapter.clients((err, clients) => {
   console.log(clients); // an array containing all connected socket ids
});

io.of('/').adapter.clients(['room1', 'room2'], (err, clients) => {
   console.log(clients);
});

// you can also use

io.in('room3').clients((err, clients) => {
   console.log(clients); // an array containing socket ids in 'room3'
});
```